# ng-bind-html retirando style

Tags: html, angularjs

Estou tentando passar um `style` em um span, mais quando eu uso o ng-bing-html ele retira

No json que é colocado na pagina até esta com o `style`

```
<script id="data" type="application/json" product-data>
<p><span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">PEDIDO M&Iacute;NIMO:&nbsp;10 UNIDADES&nbsp;<\/span><\/p>
```

Mais quando uso

```
        <div itemprop="description" ng-bind-html="product.summary"></div>
```

Resultado na pagina

```
<p><span>PEDIDO MÍNIMO:&nbsp;10 UNIDADES&nbsp;</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentar usar o `$sce.trustAsHtml()` no controller, para não perder o CSS.